# Data is null when capturing photo with camera (Nexus 7)

Tags: android-camera, android-camera-intent

On some phones when I use the camera to load a new photo into an ImageView, the data I get back is null. On other phones it works fine. It works on most Kitkat phone's, but not on a Nexus 7 (4.4.2) and who know's on what else.

Works on HTC M8 (5.0.1), HTC Desire X (4.1.1), Samsung Galaxy S4 (4.4.2), Samsung Galaxy S5 (5.0).

I share only the code for capturing images on Kitkat, but I handle them differently when I am working with bitmap conversions and upload to server.

```
btn_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
           Log.i("INTENT0", "PICK_FROM_CAMERA_KITKAT");
           Intent intentPicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           startActivityForResult(intentPicture,PICK_FROM_CAMERA_KITKAT);
           dialog_newimg.dismiss();
    }
});

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
       switch (requestCode) {
           case PICK_FROM_CAMERA_KITKAT:
             if (data != null) {
                Log.i("data.getData()", data.getData() + ""); //null
                [...many things..]
             }
    ...
    }
}
```

I read some similar questions and I highlight that I don't use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in any way.

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean the `Intent data` received by `onActivityResult()` is **null**, or `data.getData()` returns **null**?

Comment: I mean data.getData() is null.

Comment: @erdomester Have you found any solution yet? I just came across this problem as well.

Comment: I posted an answer. If the code is missing anything just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this. Actually the key is to handle the Uri differently:

```
if (data.getData() == null) {
      selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileForCamera_);  
} else {
      selectedImageUri = data.getData();
}
```

After this it's also important to handle the path differently with the helper functions `getRealPathFromURI()` for above Kitkat and `getPath()` for below Kitkat.

I post my whole code here as a reference for others. This code has been working for 2 months now in all kinds of devices of hundreds of users without force closes.

```
case PICK_FROM_CAMERA_COMPLETE:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        if (data.getData() == null) {
                            selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileForCamera_);  
                        } else {
                            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        }
                    } else {
                        selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileForCamera_);
                     }
                    complete_dialog.filename = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);

                    Bitmap bitmapSelectedImage;
                    try {
                        bitmapSelectedImage = getSampleBitmapFromFile(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri), 400, 400);
                        ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri));
                        int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                        int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(orientation);
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        if (rotationInDegrees != 0f) {
                            matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
                            bitmapSelectedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSelectedImage, 0, 0, bitmapSelectedImage.getWidth(), bitmapSelectedImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        }

                        Bitmap d = new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(), bitmapSelectedImage).getBitmap();
                        int nh = (int) ( d.getHeight() * (512.0 / d.getWidth()) );
                        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(d, 512, nh, true);
                        complete_dialog.iv_bucket2.setImageBitmap(scaled);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                    //DELETE FILE THAT WE CREATED FROM CAMERA
                }
                break;
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA_COMPLETE_KITKAT:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        if (data.getData() == null) {
                            selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileForCamera_); 
                        } else {
                            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        }
                    } else {
                        selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileForCamera_);
                    }
                    Bitmap bitmapSelectedImage2;
                    try {
                        bitmapSelectedImage2 = getSampleBitmapFromFile(getPath(BucketProfileActivity.this, selectedImageUri), 400, 400);
                        ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(getPath(BucketProfileActivity.this, selectedImageUri));
                        int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                        int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(orientation);
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        if (rotationInDegrees != 0f) {
                            matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
                            bitmapSelectedImage2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSelectedImage2, 0, 0, bitmapSelectedImage2.getWidth(), bitmapSelectedImage2.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        }
                        Bitmap d = new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(), bitmapSelectedImage2).getBitmap();
                        int nh = (int) ( d.getHeight() * (512.0 / d.getWidth()) );
                        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(d, 512, nh, true);
                        complete_dialog.iv_bucket2.setImageBitmap(scaled);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                    //DELETE FILE THAT WE CREATED FROM CAMERA
                }
                break;
            case LOAD_FROM_GALLERY_COMPLETE:  //before KitKat
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        complete_dialog.show();
                        Uri imageuri = data.getData();
                        complete_dialog.filename = getRealPathFromURI(imageuri);

                        Bitmap bitmapSelectedImage3;
                        try {
                            bitmapSelectedImage3 = getSampleBitmapFromFile(getRealPathFromURI(imageuri), 400, 400);
                            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(getRealPathFromURI(imageuri));
                            int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                            int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(orientation);
                            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                            if (rotationInDegrees != 0f) {
                                matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
                                bitmapSelectedImage3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSelectedImage3, 0, 0, bitmapSelectedImage3.getWidth(), bitmapSelectedImage3.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                            }

                            Bitmap d = new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(), bitmapSelectedImage3).getBitmap();
                            int nh = (int) ( d.getHeight() * (512.0 / d.getWidth()) );
                            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(d, 512, nh, true);

                            complete_dialog.iv_bucket2.setImageBitmap(scaled);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                   }
                } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                    //DELETE FILE THAT WE CREATED FROM CAMERA
                }
                break;
            case LOAD_FROM_GALLERY_KITKAT_COMPLETE:  //after KitKat                         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        complete_dialog.show();
                        Uri imageuri = data.getData();
                        complete_dialog.filename = getPath(BucketProfileActivity.this, imageuri);
                        Bitmap bitmapSelectedImage4;
                        try {
                            bitmapSelectedImage4 = getSampleBitmapFromFile(getPath(BucketProfileActivity.this, imageuri), 400, 400);
                            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(getPath(BucketProfileActivity.this, imageuri));
                            int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                            int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(orientation);
                            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                            if (rotationInDegrees != 0f) {
                                matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
                                bitmapSelectedImage4 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSelectedImage4, 0, 0, bitmapSelectedImage4.getWidth(), bitmapSelectedImage4.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                            }

                            Bitmap d = new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(), bitmapSelectedImage4).getBitmap();
                            int nh = (int) ( d.getHeight() * (512.0 / d.getWidth()) );
                            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(d, 512, nh, true);

                            complete_dialog.iv_bucket2.setImageBitmap(scaled);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                                                }
                } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                    //DELETE FILE THAT WE CREATED FROM CAMERA
                }
                break;
```

Helper functions:

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        String result;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, "", null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            //Log.i("IDX", idx + "");
           // Log.i("RESULT", cursor.getString(idx) + "");
            result = cursor.getString(idx); //force close here
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```